# navbar not going to the right page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to let the navbar respond for the `onClick` to go to the right page. But like not even responding if I click it will appear on the link like this `http://localhost:3000/%5Bobject%20Object%5D#$%7Bitem%7D`.

I like if I click on about it will slide down and go to the about section and so on, this is the navbar code:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { HiMenuAlt4, HiX } from "react-icons/hi";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { images } from "../../constants";
import "./Navbar.scss";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  return (
    <nav className="app__navbar">
      <div className="app__navbar-logo">
        <img src={images.logo} alt="logo" />
      </div>
      <ul className="app__navbar-links">
        {["home", "about", "work", "skills", "testimonials", "contact"].map(
          (item) => (
            <li className="app__flex p-text" key={"link-#${item}"}>
              <div />
              <a href={"#${item}"}>{item}</a>
            </li>
          ),
        )}
      </ul>
      <div className="app__navbar-menu">
        <HiMenuAlt4 onClick={() => setToggle(true)} />
        {toggle && (
          <motion.div
            whileInView={{ x: [300, 0] }}
            transition={{ duration: 0.85, ease: "easeOut" }}
          >
            <HiX onClick={() => setToggle(false)} />
            <ul>
              {[
                "home",
                "about",
                "work",
                "skills",
                "testimonials",
                "contact",
              ].map((item) => (
                <li key={{ item }}>
                  <a href={"#${item}"} onClick={() => setToggle(false)}>
                    {item}
                  </a>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </motion.div>
        )}
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do. You're talking about "pages" but at the moment you seem to want to just navigate to an element on the current page identified by the hash and _not_ a separate route within the SPA (for which react-router might be preferable).

Comment: I found the solution I change the {"#${item}"} to {`#${item}`} that is it  thank you everyone who try to help